# Return a different code depending on the value of a variable

Tags: javascript

In a function I want to return a different code depending on the value of a variable.

How to do that if the value of param1 == '-999' we do not test condition 1 (test 1).
I could do a test for each param but I have 12 that would be so (12 * 12 = 144 test).
This is for filter system, the value of param is equal to '-999' when the filter of this parameter is not checked. So we do not want to test this parameter.

```
var param1 = 'boy'; // value can be 'girl','-999'
var param2 = '12'; // value can be '20','-999'
var param3 = 'red'; // value can be 'blue','-999'

function(feature, param1, param2, param3){

    return (
        feature.properties.parameter1 == param1 && // test 1
        feature.properties.parameter2 == param2 && // test 2
        feature.properties.parameter3 == param3    // test 3
    )   

}
```

Comment: A little unclear what you need here... can you show an example value for `feature.properties` ? And based on the values you show on snippet for `param1`, `param2`, `param3`, what does the function should output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly, you'd add a nested or, like this:

```
function(feature, param1, param2, param3){

    return (
        (param1==='-999' // bypass test1 if param1 is '-999'
          || feature.properties.parameter1 == param1) && // test 1
        feature.properties.parameter2 == param2 && // test 2
        feature.properties.parameter3 == param3    // test 3
    )   

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that's exactly what I was looking for !